# Android: Dismissing popup window in onPause when it's created in a separate method

Tags: java, android, popupwindow, timertask

I have a **separate** method in my code that creates a **popup window:**

```
private void showPopup(final Activity context, int[] buttonLocation) {

    // CREATE POPUP HERE NAMED popup

    // Display popup for 600ms (it's a popup with an animation)
    final Timer t1 = new Timer();
    TimerTask titty1 = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Romp.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    popup.dismiss();
                    t1.cancel();
                    t1.purge();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t1.schedule(titty1, 600);
}
```

When I close my activity elsewhere in the code, and try to go back to the previous activity, I get a "leaked window" error, inferring that I need to dismiss my popup. I dismiss my popup in the timer shown above, however, there's another part of my code that can trigger the activity to end in the mean time.

I want to be able to do something like this in on **destroy/pause:**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ACTIVITY.this.finish();
    eraseData();
    popup.dismiss();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Is there a way I can dismiss a popup window from onDestroy/pause that was created in a separate method?

Answer (score 0):

reason for the **leaked window** is that it is not syncing with the activity it was linked and not closed when the activity closes. So better while accessing the UI elements make sure that the activity is alive.

```
boolean alive=true;

@Override public void onDestroy() {

    alive=false;
    ACTIVITY.this.finish();
    eraseData();
    popup.dismiss();
    super.onDestroy(); }

private void showPopup(final Activity context, int[] buttonLocation) {

    // CREATE POPUP HERE NAMED popup

    // Display popup for 600ms (it's a popup with an animation)
    final Timer t1 = new Timer();
    TimerTask titty1 = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Romp.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!alive)
                        return;
                    popup.dismiss();
                    t1.cancel();
                    t1.purge();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t1.schedule(titty1, 600);
}
```

follow the same before creating the popup.

Comment: Won't this still give me issues once the animation has started playing already and the activity's onPause is called?

Comment: no issues, because once the activity is closed, the pop up element will also be closed. so there wont be an access to deleted element. Since u are using a separate thread, u should check whether the element is alive or not. The same case is for onPause also the difference is the state will be idle not deleted.

Answer (score -1):

call-

```
titty1.cancel(true);
t1.cacncel();
```

in your `onPause()`/`onDestroy()` according to your use case/requirement.

### Update

```
class Test{
  private final Timer t1 = new Timer();
  private TimerTask titty1=null;
  private void showPopup(final Activity context, int[] buttonLocation) {

    // CREATE POPUP HERE NAMED popup

    // Display popup for 600ms (it's a popup with an animation)
    titty1 = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Romp.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!alive)
                        return;
                    popup.dismiss();
                    t1.cancel();
                    t1.purge();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t1.schedule(titty1, 600);
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {

    alive=false;
    ACTIVITY.this.finish();
    eraseData();
    popup.dismiss();
    titty1.cancel(true);
    t1.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

Comment: But how, as they aren't declared in the scope of the onDestroy / Pause methods? "titty1 is not delcared in this scope"

Also, I apologize for the childish naming scheme, sometimes I get bored while I work.

Comment: haha, naimg is just fine, we all get bored :). You have to create the scope. Can't you make it a member of the class? then you will be able to access it from onDestro/onPause. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Amit, could you provide me with an example of how to do this? Being a self taught coder, I've never worked with making members of classes and such. Thanks!

Comment: This still hasn't solved my problem unfortunately. I'm going to remove popup windows completely. The reason why I have been using them is because I want to show an animation when you click a button. I tried setting the background of the button as an animation drawable, but was getting similar issues when switching between activities while an animation was running.